# How to find and manipulate an element generated by a widget in WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, themes

I went through a ton of articles trying to find some sort of answer to this seemingly fundamental question about WordPress, but couldn't find a match. Forgive me if this has been gone over before.

I am new to WordPress and the company I work for uses it to build many of its sites for clients. They use Yoo Themes and UIKit for styling. I was recently tasked with moving a simple block of color with some text in it from the bottom of the page (just above the footer) to the top of the page (just before the header/navbar). I spent three hours trying to find which widget it was a part of only to be lost in a morass of vaguely descriptive widget bars in the customize panel. I found the one with the text in it, but after I moved it, the color bar remained.

**My question is: is there a fast and hopefully easy way to tell what widget is displaying a particular element, or set of elements, and then upon finding it, moving it in the manner I described above?**

I have used Chrome's DevTools which reveal the nests within nests that a WP site is, but it only got me to the "Top A" widget for the text, not the green bar area. This is super simple in straight HTML/CSS, but I am a little lost with WordPress.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.